# WordPress endpoints on custom taxonomy fail

Tags: wordpress, endpoint, custom-taxonomy

We have a directory of beaches throughout California using a WordPress site with a custom post type (beach) and a hierarchical custom taxonomy (region).

I am trying to add an endpoint for the 'region' custom taxonomy. The organizes the state of California into 3 main regions (Northern, Central, Southern). The taxonomy is hierarchical as then for each region it has counties. Within each county we then show our custom post type, in this case beaches.

```
register_taxonomy( 'region',
    array('beach'),
    array( 
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('hierarchical' => true, 'ep_mask' => EP_ALL ),
        'label' => 'Regions',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
        'labels' => array (
            'name'              => _x( 'Regions', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Region', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Regions' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Regions' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Region' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent REgion:' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Region' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Region' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Region' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Region Name' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Regions' ),
        )
    )
);
```

Then I try to add an endpoint, 'dogs', so when viewing a county level term we can see all beaches which are dog friendly.

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'dogs', EP_ALL );
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Instead of still querying for the term and adding the new query_var 'dogs', it somehow ends up pulling an attachment page somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there was actually a conflict with another plugin causing issues, disabling that plugin and endpoints for taxonomies works as expected.